# Ubuntu: One or more of the mounts listed in fstab cannot ye be mounted

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

I was enjoying a Movie when my Ubuntu suddenly hung.
At the next reboot, here is the message:

```
One or more of the mounts listed in /etc/fstab cannot yet be mounted:
/home: waiting for /dev/disk/by-uuid/....
Press ESC to enter a recovery shell.
```

Problems: When I enter recovery shell, I don't know that to do. If I press Ctrl+D, then the message above will reappear.

What should I do? I checked with Ubuntu Live CD and my partition looks OK. I have 2 separate partitions for `/` and `/home`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that it can not find the partition where /home is. If it was on a separate disk then this disk may have gone bad.

For starters I'd comment the line in /etc/fstab and reboot. Then you can start to investigate what went wrong with the partition (fdisk, etc). One option is to replace the /dev/disk/by/id with the /dev/sdxx designation.

I usually get such messages on servers with filesystems on SAN disks when there is a problem with the driver. This can happen during upgrades, for example, the solution is to fix the driver to make the partition accessible again.

Comment: +1 Can't add anything to this. You need to use fdisk to "see" the disk and then try to mount it manually by device eg /dev/sdb2. Then add it to fstab.

Comment: I changed the setting from `UUID=xxxxx /home ext4 defaults` to `/dev/sda9 /home ext4 defaults`. Now it is saying the same message: `/home: wating for /dev/sda9`. `/home` and `/` are on the same disk.

Comment: I boot my computer using Ubuntu LIve CD and run fsck /dev/sda9 so that errors on my disk can be fixed. After that, my Ubuntu started to boot normally. Thank you.